# What Wireless Adapter can I use for installation?

Tags: installation, wireless, drivers

I'm new to Linux and I want to install it on a couple of desktop computers I am no longer using. (Pentium 4, 2GB RAM each).

Is there a wireless USB adapter I can use to be connected to my WiFi during the installation? I have a couple of old ones lying around... linksys and netgear. Any chance one of these might work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Make a Live USB/DVD following directions from ubuntu.com. 2. Boot from the Live USB/DVD. 3. Choose "Try Ubuntu without Installing." 4. Test WiFi adapter and other hardware with Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi Rob, it would help if you could give the model numbers of the wireless dongles, however with the install cd you get the chance to test Ubuntu before install, this will let you test if the Wireless card works before committing to an install.

Comment: Beat me haha! close though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up beginning the install from a CD, and when it came to the point of installation where it was talking about connecting to the network, I tried plugging in a Linksys adapter... worked without a hitch. Thanks anyway.